# Printer cannot print in colour when I print from my computer. Reinstalling printer doesn’t fix things

Tags: printing, printer, colors

I have a presentation that looks like this, and I want to print it.

> [image: Image 1]

I head to print it, but even *after* selecting print in colour, it still comes out like this.

> [image: Image 2]

I select `properties`, then `advanced`, but there is no option to print colour.

> [image: Image 3]

After doing some research, I found out I need to go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers` and right-click on my printer then click “Printer Preferences.”

This is what others see in their printer preferences:

> [image: Image 4]

And this is what I see in printer preferences:

> [image: Image 5]

Is there anyway I can fix this so I can print in colour? FWIW, reinstalling the printer also does not work.

Comment: Fully uninstall the printer (and all the bits for it) normally in Control Panel, Programs and Features. Restart the computer, install the printer and set it up. Test for color.

Comment: @John , nope, still does not work. Same as before.

Comment: So either the printer is incompatible (don't think so but check) or there is an issue with the operating system. You can Repair Install a modern operating system.

Comment: @John, My printer used to be ok. Is there any way else besides reinstalling the OS, as I do not wish to have all my apps deleted?

Comment: If Windows 10, do a Windows 10 Repair Install and start with the option to Keep Everything. See if that works.

Comment: When actually *printing*, right-click on the Brother printer, select *Properties*, and try to set *Grayscale* off. If that choice is not available there, then try DISM and SFC repairs: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sfc-scannow-and-dismexe-online-cleanup-image/db3b24de-a261-403e-9d11-8141d13f7954 . If that doesn't work, *then* re3install Windows, keeping files.

Answer (score -1):

"Microsoft IPP Class Driver" – seems Windows chose a generic driver that doesn't have color capability.

You can download your printer driver from Brother's site: https://www.brother-usa.com/support/mfcl3770cdw

In general, it also helps to check *Windows Settings > Update & Security* to see if anything better than a generic built-in driver can be found.